# How to allow egress traffic on 443 port (https calls) and block 80 port (http calls)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I am implementing kubernetes network policy for my app on K3s. I want to allow `egress` (external call to internet from pod) for port `443` i.e. `https` calls ***only*** and deny/block all egress calls on `80` port i.e. `http`. In short, allow `https` egress calls and deny `http` egress calls.
I am testing this with below `custom-dns.yaml` file:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: foo-deny-egress
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: foo
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
  # allow DNS resolution
  - ports:
    - port: 443
      protocol: UDP
    - port: 443
      protocol: TCP
```

After `kubectl apply -f custom-dns.yaml` I create and login to pod :`kubectl run --restart=Never pod-v1 --image=busybox -i -t -l app=foo` and test the http and https url by command:

1. `wget https://www.google.com`
2. `wget http://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/my-drive`

Both the wget commands are giving `wget: bad address` error. 
But when I do not apply this network policy, the same wget commands are working & giving below result from same pod:
**i.**

```
        wget https://www.google.com
        Connecting to www.google.com (172.217.167.164:443)
        wget: note: TLS certificate validation not implemented
        saving to 'index.html'
        index.html           100% |******************************************************| 15264  0:00:00 ETA
       'index.html' saved
```

**ii.**

```
wget http://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/my-drive
Connecting to drive.google.com (142.250.192.46:80)
Connecting to drive.google.com (142.250.192.46:443)
wget: note: TLS certificate validation not implemented
Connecting to accounts.google.com (142.250.192.77:443)
saving to 'my-drive'
my-drive             100% |******************************************************| 92019  0:00:00 ETA
'my-drive' saved
```

**iii.** `Telnet` to google.com IP `172.217.167.164` with `80` & `443` port happening

```
#telnet 172.217.166.164 80
Connected to 172.217.166.164
^]q
# telnet 172.217.166.164 443
Connected to 172.217.166.164
^]
```

**iv.** Similarly `Telnet` to drive.com IP `142.250.192.46` with `80` & `443` port happening

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- networkPolicy you have mentioned in the post just allows https/traffic on 443 but you have not mentioned anything in it to deny http(port 80) traffic.
- There are two ways to achieve it :

  - Setup a default deny policy for egress

  either

  - create another egress policy where you deny egress on port 80

Comment: Hi @confusedGenius. So by denying all egress calls , and creating another egress policy to deny Port 80 calls, where am I accepting port 443 calls? Can you give some config example for this ?

Comment: If i understood correctly he means that in addition to your(properly) created `allow` policy, you should create `deny` one. And the most convenient way is to "create another egress policy where you deny egress on port 80". You dont need implement two solutions.

Comment: btw, nice networkpolicies online emulator, you can try it. https://editor.cilium.io/